# VBA Find Loop Missing Occurances

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I'm trying to process a Word document and simply bold all of a specific term. The problem is that when I run the following code on a test paragraph with 7 occurrences of my search term, only two of them get bolded. I've tried it with different words in the paragraph and it always seems to turn up about a quarter of the actual number. An interesting feature that I can't confirm to be universal, but seems to be so is that the first term is always skipped, it bolds one occurrence, skips two, gets one, and so on. I've also tried changing the options on find around to no avail.

```
Sub HighlightTerm()

    Dim highRange As Range
    Set highRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    Do
        With highRange.Find
            .Text = "inflation"
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Execute
        End With

        If highRange.Find.Execute Then
            highRange.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Loop While highRange.Find.Execute

End Sub
```

Any help or suggestions on how to fix this problem, or new code that accomplishes what I want, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nemmy's answer is absolutely correct, I just wanted to point out that there's the Find property "Found" so that if I would have replaced the second two instances of "highRange.Find.Execute" with "highRange.Find.Found" it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because each time you run the highRange.Find.Execute method you do another search.  I see that you execute it three times in your loop.  Perhaps you should try something like this:

```
    Sub HighlightTerm()

    Dim highRange As Range
    Dim blnFound as boolean
    Set highRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    Do
        With highRange.Find
            .Text = "inflation"
            .MatchWholeWord = True
        End With

        blnFound=highRange.Find.Execute

        If blnFound Then
            highRange.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Loop While blnFound

   End Sub
```

*disclaimer code not tested.